# Increment count on page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am trying to create a thumbnails pagination using Jquery. everything is working perfectly fine. My only problem is I do not know how to increment count on each page load. Below is my code. My main goal is, if the user click the next button, I want to increment 1 on this 
php/reverse.php?page="+page. If there are no more result from php, do not allow to increment anymore. Same thing on previous button.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="par"></div>
      <input type="button" id="prev" value="Prev"/>
      <input type="button" id="next" value="Next"/>

      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
        var default_val = 1;
        function get_page(page){
          $.ajax({
            url: "php/reverse.php?page="+page
          }).done(function(data) {
            $('#par').html(data.thumbs);
          });
        }

        $('#prev').click(function(){
            get_page(default_val)
        });


        $('#next').click(function(){
         get_page(default_val+1)
        });

        get_page(default_val);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
  require '../php/connect.inc.php';
  $per_page = 4;

  $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM my_list");
  $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

  $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
  $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;


  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, image_small FROM my_list LIMIT $start, $per_page");

  $results = array();
  while($mysql_fetch_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    $results[] = "<img src='img/".$mysql_fetch_assoc['image_small']."'/>";
  }      


  header('Content-type: application/json');

  echo json_encode(array(
    'thumbs' => $results,
    'pages' => $pages,
    'current_page' => $page,
    'per_page' => $per_page
  ));
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 0):

first you need to return status of request

```
var page = 1;
function get_page(page){
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "php/reverse.php?page="+page
  }).done(function(data) {
    if (data.thumbs.length>0) {
      $('#par').html(data.thumbs);
      return true; // here
    } else
      return false; // and here
  });
}
```

next, what you want is blocking function when json will return false and increase or decrease page count

```
var block_next = false,
    block_prev = false;

$('#prev').click(function(){
  block_next = false;
  if (!block_prev)
    if (!get_page(page))
      block_prev = true;
    else
      page = page - 1;
});

$('#next').click(function(){
  block_prev = false;
  if (!block_next)
    get_page(page+1)
      block_next = true;
    else
      page = page + 1;
});
```